ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl' running Python3.9
I'm trying to configure a virtual environment with Python3.9 (with other distributions works without problem) in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but I got the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
I tried with the following solutions found in different posts but none of them worked:

Reinstalling  ssl with sudo apt reinstall libssl-dev,
Installing Python3.9 from source including the flag --with-openssl=/usr/lib/ssl when running ./configure,
Following the instructions of this post but for Python3.9

Any idea?

How do you configure/setup the virtual environment?

I tried automatically with PyCharm and manually with python3.9 -m venv venv

Have you checked the timestamp of the python3.9 binaries - that they do change after the build? Also, running python3.9 -V might help to determine the build version in /usr/local/bin or similar location.
